# Table Designer Toolbar Disabled in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

There are similar questions on SO and the Internet regarding the Query Designer tools in Visual Studio, but I can't find any reference to the Table Designer.  I'm trying to use VS2013  Pro to design SQL Server database tables (generating SQL scripts in a project, not creating/editing them live on a SQL Server) and I'm almost certain that I've done this before in VS2013, but when I've come to do so today, the Table Designer toolbar is greyed out and I don't know why.

[image: Table Designer Toolbar appears disabled]

I know I can achieve the same things as the toolbar does by editing the T-SQL, but I'd prefer to do it with the GUI tools which I've used in the past!  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here, did you end up finding a fix/workaround ?

Comment: Nope, never got to the bottom of it, just got stuck into the T-SQL which, to be fair, has probably helped me get some syntax firmly in my head, but definitely takes longer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is no longer possible in Visual Studio 2013.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5a4ezk9.aspx