# I can not use "Table Designer" in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to learn asp.net in Visual Studio and the "table designer" button is not active. What should I do? I downloaded all asp.net and database plugins.

[image: "Tablo Tasarlayıcısı" means table designer]

I wanted to use the "Table Designer" button and the button remained inactive.

Comment: Sounds like it may have been deprecated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916086/table-designer-toolbar-disabled-in-vs2013 Not sure if this is about the same tool or not

Comment: If I were you I would do myself a favour and stay away from Web Forms in favour of the much more modern ASP.NET Core and MVC or Razor Pages.

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to inform you that [Table Designer is a deprecated toolset](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d83f8597-95bd-43e1-9492-d18e93c1e212/database-toolbars-greyed-out-no-designer?forum=ssdt).

But you can use other tools to design tables in Visual Studio, for example, I am using local sqlserver:

View=>SQL Server Object Explorer => Right-click SQL Server => Add Sql Server => Browse => Select the database you want to connect to and click Connect

At this time, you can see that there are more servers in SQL Server Object Explorer.

[image]

Now you can design the database tables in Visual Studio.

[image]